# 18.04: Kernel Panic with Asus Prime x299, Titan V

Tags: nvidia, kernel, asus, error-handling, opencv

I'm using my linux machine for computer vision. When i running a feature detection with opencv i get in aprox. 25% cases a kernel panic
(e.g. I run something like this: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-alpha/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_orb/py_orb.html)

**Things I tried to fix/understand the problem:**

- I tried Ubuntu 17.10 and 16.04: In this versions I get a kernel panic when i try to boot the life system.
- I installed crash dump and mcelog but i dont get any further dump information about the kernel panic
- Checked the entire memory: no errors found
- Started the calculation without desktop manager (e.g. in tty2): same problem
- disabled all cpu features in the bios (e.g: hyperthreading, virtualization...): same problem

Here are my lshw output:

```
sudo lshw -short
H/W path               Device     Class          Description
============================================================
                                  system         System Product Name (SKU)
/0                                bus            PRIME X299-DELUXE
/0/0                              memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/4c                             memory         System Memory
/0/4c/0                           memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
/0/4c/1                           memory         DIMM Synchronous [empty]
/0/4c/2                           memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
/0/4c/3                           memory         DIMM Synchronous [empty]
/0/54                             memory         System Memory
/0/54/0                           memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
/0/54/1                           memory         DIMM Synchronous [empty]
/0/54/2                           memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
/0/54/3                           memory         DIMM Synchronous [empty]
/0/5c                             memory         1152KiB L1 cache
/0/5d                             memory         18MiB L2 cache
/0/5e                             memory         24MiB L3 cache
/0/5f                             processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-7980XE CPU @ 2.60GHz
/0/1                              memory         
/0/2                              memory         
/0/100                            bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/4                          generic        Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
/0/100/4.1                        generic        Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
/0/100/4.2                        generic        Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
/0/100/4.3                        generic        Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
/0/100/4.4                        generic        Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
/0/100/4.5                        generic        Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
/0/100/4.6                        generic        Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
/0/100/4.7                        generic        Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
/0/100/5                          generic        Sky Lake-E MM/Vt-d Configuration Registers
/0/100/5.2                        generic        Intel Corporation
/0/100/5.4                        generic        Intel Corporation
/0/100/8                          generic        Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers
/0/100/8.1                        generic        Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers
/0/100/8.2                        generic        Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers
/0/100/14                         bus            200 Series PCH USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
/0/100/14/0            usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/6                     bus            ASM107x
/0/100/14/0/7                     input          USB Receiver
/0/100/14/0/d                     communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14/0/e                     input          AURA Custom Human interface
/0/100/14/1            usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1/2          scsi7      storage        USB Reader
/0/100/14/1/2/0.0.0    /dev/sdd   disk           STORAGE DEVICE
/0/100/14/1/2/0.0.0/0  /dev/sdd   disk           
/0/100/14/1/2/0.0.1    /dev/sde   disk           STORAGE DEVICE
/0/100/14/1/2/0.0.1/0  /dev/sde   disk           
/0/100/14/1/2/0.0.2    /dev/sdf   disk           STORAGE DEVICE
/0/100/14/1/2/0.0.2/0  /dev/sdf   disk           
/0/100/14/1/2/0.0.3    /dev/sdg   disk           STORAGE DEVICE
/0/100/14/1/2/0.0.3/0  /dev/sdg   disk           
/0/100/14/1/2/0.0.4    /dev/sdh   disk           STORAGE DEVICE
/0/100/14/1/2/0.0.4/0  /dev/sdh   disk           
/0/100/14/1/6                     bus            ASM107x
/0/100/14.2                       generic        200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem
/0/100/16                         communication  200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
/0/100/17                         storage        SATA Controller [RAID mode]
/0/100/1b                         bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #17
/0/100/1b.3                       bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #20
/0/100/1b.3/0          wlp2s0     network        Wil6200 802.11ad Wireless Network Adapter
/0/100/1c                         bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #1
/0/100/1c/0                       bus            ASMedia Technology Inc.
/0/100/1c/0/0          usb3       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1c/0/1          usb4       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1c.1                       bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #2
/0/100/1c.1/0          enp4s0     network        I211 Gigabit Network Connection
/0/100/1c.2                       bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #3
/0/100/1c.2/0          wlp5s0     network        QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
/0/100/1c.4                       bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5
/0/100/1c.4/0                     bus            ASMedia Technology Inc.
/0/100/1c.4/0/0        usb5       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1c.4/0/1        usb6       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1c.6                       bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #7
/0/100/1c.6/0                     bus            ASMedia Technology Inc.
/0/100/1c.6/0/0        usb7       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1c.6/0/1        usb8       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1d                         bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9
/0/100/1d/0                       storage        NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
/0/100/1f                         bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.2                       memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3                       multimedia     200 Series PCH HD Audio
/0/100/1f.4                       bus            200 Series PCH SMBus Controller
/0/100/1f.6            enp0s31f6  network        Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
/0/3                              generic        Intel Corporation
/0/4                              generic        Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers
/0/6                              generic        Intel Corporation
/0/7                              generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/8.1                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/8.2                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/8.3                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/8.4                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/8.5                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/8.6                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/8.7                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/8                              generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/9.1                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/9.2                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/9.3                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/9.4                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/9.5                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/9.6                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/9.7                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/9                              generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/a                              generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/e                              generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/e.1                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/e.2                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/e.3                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/e.4                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/e.5                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/e.6                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/e.7                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/f                              generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/f.1                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/f.2                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/f.3                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/f.4                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/f.5                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/f.6                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/f.7                            generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/10                             generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/10.1                           generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/1d                             generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/1d.1                           generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/1d.2                           generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/1d.3                           generic        Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
/0/1e                             generic        Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
/0/1e.1                           generic        Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
/0/1e.2                           generic        Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
/0/1e.3                           generic        Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
/0/1e.4                           generic        Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
/0/1e.5                           generic        Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
/0/1e.6                           generic        Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
/0/101                            bridge         Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port 1A
/0/101/0                          display        GV100
/0/101/0.1                        multimedia     NVIDIA Corporation
/0/11                             generic        Intel Corporation
/0/13                             generic        Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers
/0/14                             generic        Intel Corporation
/0/18                             generic        Intel Corporation
/0/19                             generic        Intel Corporation
/0/1a                             generic        Intel Corporation
/0/1b                             generic        Intel Corporation
/0/a.2                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/a.3                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/a.4                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/a.5                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/a.6                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/a.7                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/b                              generic        Intel Corporation
/0/b.1                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/b.2                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/b.3                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/c                              generic        Intel Corporation
/0/c.1                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/c.2                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/c.3                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/c.4                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/c.5                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/c.6                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/c.7                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/d                              generic        Intel Corporation
/0/d.1                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/d.2                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/d.3                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/5                              generic        Intel Corporation
/0/5.2                            generic        Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers
/0/5.4                            generic        Intel Corporation
/0/12                             generic        Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers
/0/12.1                           generic        Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers
/0/12.2                           generic        Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers
/0/15                             generic        Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers
/0/16                             generic        Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers
/0/16.4                           generic        Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers
/0/17                             generic        Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers
/0/1c                  scsi2      storage        
/0/1c/0.0.0            /dev/sda   disk           1TB Samsung SSD 860
/0/1c/0.0.0/1          /dev/sda1  volume         15MiB reserved partition
/0/1c/0.0.0/2          /dev/sda2  volume         931GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1f                  scsi3      storage        
/0/1f/0.0.0            /dev/sdb   disk           1TB Samsung SSD 860
/0/1f/0.0.0/1          /dev/sdb1  volume         15MiB reserved partition
/0/1f/0.0.0/2          /dev/sdb2  volume         931GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/20                  scsi4      storage        
/0/20/0.0.0            /dev/sdc   disk           512GB Samsung SSD 850
/0/20/0.0.0/1          /dev/sdc1  volume         456GiB EXT4 volume
/0/20/0.0.0/2          /dev/sdc2  volume         20GiB Linux swap volume
/1                                power          To Be Filled By O.E.M.`enter
```

[and here is an image of the kernel panic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DMyY.jpg)

have someone same problems with Asus Prime x299, Titan V? How I can fix this problem/find the incompatible hardware device?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled Turbo Boost? It seems like lots of people are having trouble with Sky Lake CPUs and X299, with a potential solution being reducing the CPU clock speed or increasing the CPU voltage.

From discussions on the official Intel forums [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/779705):

> Intel doesn't actually seem to specify* the AVX/AVX512 speeds for the Skylake X chips. Which is probably why the mobo manufacturers seem to be getting it all wrong. Though in practice, offsets of -4 for AVX and -7 for AVX512 seem to be appropriate for stock speeds. So you can try entering those into the BIOS. If that still fails, you can try decreasing them further. But if that still doesn't work, then there are probably other issues involved.

Another one [here](https://communities.intel.com/thread/119930):

> So I just increased my cpu voltage to 1200 (the default was 0) and I let the mode to adaptive (the default anyway). And from that point the BSOD stopped! So it's like the cpu are not having enough voltage for the turbo by default. So you need to give them more voltage or they simply don't work!

Similarly, a user on the MSI forums found success increasing the CPU voltage [here](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=292772.0):

> I have a i7 7820X on MSI X299M Gaming Carbon AC, running on default BIOS settings, with BIOS v1.00.
>
> Ubuntu 17.04 amd64 would crash during boot, as would Linux Mint 18.2.  Ubuntu 17.10 beta2, as well as Debian 9.2, interestingly, boot without problem, but both were very unstable (would randomly lock up and reboot).  Windows 10 64-bit would mostly run fine, even doing a CPU stress test, though I noticed that it would blue-screen if I tried AIDA64's instruction latency test (I think it was around the AVX512 instructions, so I have my suspicions, but haven't bothered confirming).  Memtest86+ detects no problems, so it's likely not a RAM thing.
>
> I never tested disabling CPU cores, but did find that raising the CPU voltage to 1.1V caused all these issues to go away (all OSes boot, no random freezes etc).  Also upgraded to BIOS v1.30 and no issues experienced with default BIOS settings, so presumably the updated BIOS did something to fix up the power delivery or similar.

It seems the default BIOS configuration on some motherboards is not providing sufficient power to the CPU, causing unstable behavior. This might be causing your problem as well.

Personally, I've had the exact same Machine Check Error as the one in your image when running PyTorch operations on the CPU; **so far**, disabling turbo boost has made the system stable. I haven't tested the other resolution strategies yet.